# Ensuring that two separate objects have a unique total set of keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, dictionary

I have a JS framework and the user can inject values sourced from two different files. The injectable values are identified by the key of the returned object. The problem is that having two separate files means that the keys could clash.

If I have two JS objects like so:

```
let one = {
  foo: null,
  bar: null
}

let two = {
  foo: null,
  baz: null
}
```

Is there some way I could ensure the keys are unique across these two objects? I don't think there is a great way to do this, just looking for some possible ideas. Obviously, the two objects above "clash" because they both contain the key "foo".

Comment: Is this only considering flat objects? As in, not `{ foo: { foobar: null } }`?

Comment: yes that's right, just the top level key

Answer (score 3):

A vanilla js solution:

```
 if(!Object.keys(one).every(key => !(key in two))) alert("dupe");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two array keys and see if there is a duplicate

```
const one = {
  foo: null,
  bar: null
}

const two = {
  foo: null,
  baz: null
}

const array = Object.keys(one).concat(Object.keys(two));
const hasDuplicate = array.filter((item, index) => {
    return array.indexOf(item) !== -1 && index !== array.indexOf(item)
}).length !== 0;
```

Comment: This can be made faster for larger sets if you sort it after the concat; then the filter only has to compare each element to the previous one, rather than finding the index.  (O(nlogn) rather than O(n^2).)

Answer (score 1):

Just check if any key is in the other set. If so, they are not unique. Using [`some` <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is desirable here as it will break early under a match condition.

```js
function unique(obj1,obj2){
    var o2Keys = Object.keys(obj2);
    return !Object.keys(obj1).some(k => o2Keys.some(k2 => k == k2));
}

let o1 = { foo: null, bar: null };
let o2 = { foo: null, bar: null };
let o3 = { foobar: null };
let o4 = { bar: null };

console.log(unique(o1,o2)); //false
console.log(unique(o1,o3)); //true
console.log(unique(o1,o4)); //false
```